# Is this iPad screen flex cable glued onto the contacts?

Tags: display, glue, flex

[image]

While trying to change the LCD driver PCB of an iPad screen, I noticed that the flex cables coming from the display are not soldered but glued onto the PCB.

The flex cable on the right was cut from the PCB. The line where the see through glue ends is still visible.

Does someone know what kind of glue (if at all) has been used?

Comment: Before you vote to close this question, please consider that it's a useful electronics question. It is not asking how to repair a device but rather what technology was used.

Answer (score 9):

This looks like an ACF ([anisotropic conductive film](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anisotropic_conductive_film)) or ACP (anisotropic conductive paste) type bonding rather than the older (and usually low density) heat reflow technique.

It's heat bonded with a rather expensive and complex machine in a production situation. Rework is [apparently possible](https://youtu.be/btw375M6lSY) (YT video link).

The magic is in the film, the parts just need to be very clean and aligned  together with the film in between and then bonded with controlled pressure and a controlled pulse of heat. Description from [here](https://www.resonac.com/jp/solution/tech/acf.html):

[image]

Answer (score 6):

This kind of connection is called "hot bar bonding". Both the PCB and the flex cable are manufactured in such a way that they can be bonded (essentially welded) together by a hot metal bar that applies high pressure and high temperature uniformly across the entire connection. The PCB and cable must be made from special materials for this to work. You also need a hot press for the actual bonding.

It's hard to tell from the picture, but it seems like the flex cable was made from stacked layers of polymer foils - one (or more) layers on the back with high temperature resistance that provide structural stability during the bonding process, and another layer made of a weldable (lower melting point) polymer applied between the pads that bonds to the PCB under heat and pressure. (Delaminated leftovers of this layer can be seen stuck to the PCB.) The pads themselves were also likely coated with a thin layer of lower melting point metal.

Unfortunately, this kind of bonding is a one-time process - once bonded, the surfaces of both the PCB and the flex cable are permanently altered, as evident in your photo. They can't be bonded again.